# Wordpress Menu + Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm now stuck with this problem below, and I hope you can help me out. I would really appreciate it.

1st -- I created the Wordpress Menu (got it all worked).
2nd -- I implemented the Bootstrap classes (e.g nav navbar-nav, dropdown, dropdown-menu etc..) on the html tags of the Wordpress Menu. (got it and made it work somehow)
3rd -- To make the dropdowns work I used (preg_place) to replace the default (submenu) to (dropdown-menu) then to make the function work I used the (preg-replace) again to INSERT a class and data-toggle to the Anchor Links.

Now the problem is, the anchor links doesn't seem to function right at all.

[check it out here.](http://www.afpmarcom.com/beta/~afp2016/)
(use the navs on top)

HEres the code on the function.php

```
function new_submenu_class($menu) {
$menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="dropdown-menu" /',$menu);  
return $menu;  
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','new_submenu_class');

function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
$ulclass = preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"', $ulclass);
return $ulclass;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
```

Thanks much guys!

And btw.. i used a jQuery for the 3rd level submenu. which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
var $el = $(this);
var $parent = $(this).offsetParent(".dropdown-menu");
$(this).parent("li").toggleClass('open');
if(!$parent.parent().hasClass('nav')) {
$el.next().css({"top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4});
    }

    $('.nav li.open').not($(this).parents("li")).removeClass("open");

    return false;
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your sub navs have a drop-down toggle class, thats y they are not working

Comment: I don't exactly know how to fix your code, but you can take a look at: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 0):

In the function, I would try to change this line:

```
$('.navbar a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
```

For this one:

```
$('.navbar').on('click', 'a.dropdown-toggle', function(e) {
```

Since `a.dropdown-toggle` has been happended...
Maybe it was not present on "document ready", so the "[delagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)" syntax could help.